# /etc/hosts changes aren't getting reflected on Mac

Tags: macos, network, dns, hosts

I've a Spring Boot application which uses an external service. I want to reproduce a scenario where that service is not reachable after my application is up and running.

So, I thought I'll start my service and update the **/etc/hosts** entry to block the outgoing calls to that service. Somehow this is not working for my Mac.

This is how the **URL** of that **external service** looks like:

```
pulsar+ssl://a943.chat.extservice.com:6951?preset=low_tp_no_read
```

And this is the entry of **/etc/hosts**:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

# Block external service calls
0.0.0.0         pulsar+ssl://a943.chat.extservice.com:6951?preset=low_tp_no_read
0.0.0.0         a943.chat.extservice.com
0.0.0.0         pulsar+ssl://a943.chat.extservice.com:6951
0.0.0.0         a943.chat.extservice.com:6951
```

I tried adding all possible combinations but this is not working. Even I blocked google.com, but still I was able to access it.

Any suggestions or help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The format of the first, third and fourth lines is not correct: you can't specify protocols (like `pulsar+ssl`), ports (like `3369`) nor parameters (`preset=low_tp_no_read`) in `/etc/hosts`. Additionally, I'd use `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`, so you could try `127.0.0.1        a943.chat.extservice.com`.

Comment: @jaume - it's about how Hosts works on Mac… I don't see how that's 'not about Apple'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hosts doesn't block ports or services, it redirects domains, usually to 127.0.0.1
[0.0.0.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) used to 'block' can be ambiguous, as it can either mean 'no route to host' or it can mean 'use your default route'.

You may also need to reboot before it will work, unless you use something like [Gas Mask](https://github.com/2ndalpha/gasmask) which can force a reload, or try
`sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`
from Terminal

You might have some success with
`127.0.0.1    extservice.com`
but I have no way to test.

As a long-shot, it may also be initially connecting over IPv6, so try setting that to Link Local.

There's also this, from [Stack Overflow: Why does /etc/hosts not work anymore for some websites on Big Sur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65972371/why-does-etc-hosts-not-work-anymore-for-some-websites-on-big-sur) - which is way above my pay-grade.

Comment: To block/redirect IPv6 as well as IPv4, add a second line to /etc/hosts like `::1 extservice.com` (analogous to `127.0.0.1`) or `:: extservice.com` (analogous to `0.0.0.0`). However, I don't think this'll solve the HTTPS record thing described in that link. BTW, I've never needed to do any reset at all to get changes to /etc/hosts recognized by the system resolver (although it sometimes needs a reset for other reasons, and things like browsers sometimes do their own caching).